# How to make overlay still work inside lstlisting environment?

Tags: beamer, listings

### Problem

I want to explain C# programming language step by step using overlay in `beamer.cls`. But it does NOT works as shown in the following figure.

How to solve this problem?

---

### Code Snippet

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\Lst{%
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}]
using System;
public delegate void Foo(object o);
\uncover<1>{public class Foo}
\uncover<2>{\{}
\uncover<3>{public static void Main()}
\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{frame}{MyListing}
\Lst
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use the `semiverbatim` environment, it is more flexible in this case. Here is an example how I did it some time ago:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Matrixoperationen}{Benutzung von \texttt{semiverbatim}}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries,family=\ttfamily}
\begin{semiverbatim} \small
\uncover<1->{\alert<0>{\alert<6>{sub \color{red}matrix_row2vector} \{}}
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{  my $m = shift;    my($rows,$cols) = ($m->[1],$m->[2]);}}
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{  my $r = shift;   # optional, which column from matrix}}
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{  croak "Error: matrix hasn't 3D rows" unless ($colsRun also:>{}>3);}}
\uncover<3->{\alert<3>{  if ( defined $r ) \{}}
\uncover<3->{\alert<3>{    croak "Error: matrix hasn't that row" unless ($r < $rows);}}
\uncover<3->{\alert<3>{  \}}}
\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{  else \{}}
\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{    croak "Error: matrix is not a 3D row matrix"}}
\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{           unless ($rowsRun also: >>  1);}}
\uncover<5->{\alert<5>{    $r = 0;}}
\uncover<4->{\alert<4>{  \}}}
\uncover<6->{\alert<6>{  return Math::VectorReal->%
\alert<6>{\color{red}new(@\{$m->[0][$r]\})};}}
\uncover<1->{\alert<1>{\}}}
\end{semiverbatim}

\visible<6>{Beachte den Gebrauch von \alert{\color{red}\texttt{shift}}.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you have a lot of TeX code to show then define something like

```
\def\Lcs#1{\textbackslash#1}
```

then it easier to write something like \Lcs{newpage}.

Comment: Hi, does anybody know how to use lstlisting to get syntaxhighlighting?

Comment: @Tobi: That should have been posted as a fresh question.  Buried here in a comment, almost no-one will see it.

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks. I would have made an extra question but it wasn’t so important for me. I “solved“ the problem with semi transparent overlay (TikZ) so that I can focus a snippet while keeping the whole code visible. I thinks this is even better than view the code line by line. If someone likes I can make an example as another answer to this question

Comment: @Tobi: Post it.  Sounds useful (I can imagine uses for that in mathematical lectures too).

Comment: @Andrew: So should I post it here or would you like to ask a new question?

Comment: @Tobi: Post it here.  It fits here.  (I'd also like to take this opportunity to apologise to Herbert for cluttering up his inbox with irrelevant comments! - Irrelevant to his answer, that is.  Tobi, if there's anything more you wish to say or ask on this, we should continue in the chat room.)

Comment: @Tobi: That is an impressive amount of TikZ hacking - I have learned a thing or two from it! However, for the original purpose it might be a bit over-engineered :-) See my solution below.

Answer (score 47):

Even though xpert has already accepted the (frequently given) "use `semiverbatim`" answer by Herbert, I would like to present my `listings`-only solution here as well – for those like Tobi, who do not want to give up on syntax coloring and all the other cool features of the `listings` package.

The first thing to do (similar to Herbert's solution) is to not use beamer's `\defverbatim`, but to embed the listings inside the frame using the `[fragile]` option. (The whole point of `\defverbatim` is that the content is expanded *before* `\begin{frame}`, hence overlay specifications just don't work.)

The trick is then to use the `moredelim` style option of `listings` to inject the overlay-command into the listing:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[Sharp]{C}}

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=[Sharp]{C},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<+>{\color{red}}]{@}{@},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{MyListing 1}
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=base, gobble=4]
    using System;
    public delegate void Foo(object o);
    @public class Foo@
    @{@ 
    @  public static void Main()@
    @}@
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'am using `\only` instead of `\uncover`, as the formatting given by `\moredelim**` is applied *additionally* to all other formattings of the current line, which means that `\uncover` has basically no effect here.

To achive not only highlighting of the current line, but also "dimming" of the remaining parts (as in Tobi's solution), we have to play a bit more around with listing styles. The idea is to have one style (`base`) that renders the listing "dimmed" and another one (`highlight`) that is applied on top of it in the `\moredelim` command (using `\lstset`) to remove the "dimming" for the current line. This works for all style elements, but `basicstyle`, so we apply the "nondimmed"-version of `basicstyle` (which here is `\color{black}`) manually in the `moredelim` command:

```
\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
}
\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=[Sharp]{C},
  basicstyle=\color{black!40},
  keywordstyle=\color{red!40},
  commentstyle=\color{green!40},
  moredelim=**[is][\only<+>{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@}{@},
}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{MyListing 2}
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=base, gobble=4]
    using System;
    public delegate void Foo(object o);
    @public class Foo@
    @{@ 
    @  public static void Main()@
    @}@
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a very good idea :-) I’ll keep it in mind.  But why don’t you add `basicstyle=\color{black}` to `higlight`-style and remove `\color{black}` from the `moredelim`-line?

Comment: @Tobi: As explained above (albeit not very clear...) some listing styles apparently cannot be changed "in the middle" of an listing, among them `basicstyle` and `backgroundcolor`. Putting them into 'highlight` has just no effect.

Answer (score 17):

As requested my answer about using TikZ with semi transparent overlays.

### Code

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

% basic packages
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% load TikZ to draw the heighlighting areas
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \newcommand{\tikzref}[1]{% to define an anchor
        \tikz[remember picture]{%
            \coordinate (#1) at (0,0.5ex);%
        }%
    }
    \tikzset{
       transp/.style={
          fill opacity=0.75,fill=white, inner sep=1.5mm,
       },
       reverseclip/.style={
          insert path={(current page.north east) --
            (current page.south east) --
            (current page.south west) --
            (current page.north west) --
            (current page.north east)},
       },
    }

% use listings to show an example how to heighlight code
\usepackage{listings}
    \lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}
    \lstset{% 
        language=[LaTeX]TeX, 
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle={},
        escapechar={§},% needed to set tikz anchors in listings
    }


\begin{document}

% EXAMPLE A
\begin{frame}{Heighlighting parts of an equation}
% 1.  Set the equation as usual. Add anchors with \tikzmark at the beginning and
%     end of the formular, named bmath and emath in this example, and at the
%     beginning and end of the part you want to heighlight, named bfrac and efrac.
\[
    \tikzref{bmath}f(x) =
        \left(2x^4 + \tikzref{bfrac}\frac{3x^3}{4m}\tikzref{efrac}+
        7x+\pi\right)\cdot\frac{\alpha}{2\gamma\varepsilon_0}\tikzref{emath}
\]
% 2.  Add the code to highlight
% 2.1 The {tikzpicture} shouldn't take space on the frame but 'overlay' it and
%     we make the \tikzref anchors acessible via 'remember picture'.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
% 2.2 Draw the frame around the part that should be heighlighted, i.e. not coverd
%     by the semi-transparent overlay. This path has the 'clip' option meaning
%     that all following path are clipped by that.
    \path [clip] % [A, see Notes]
        ($(bfrac) - (0,5mm)$) -- %
        ($(efrac) - (0,5mm)$) -- %
        ($(efrac) + (0,5mm)$) -- %
        ($(bfrac) + (0,5mm)$) --%
        cycle
         [reverseclip];
% 2.3 Add the semi-transparent overlay to cover the whole equation.
    \node [transp,fit={($(bmath)+(0,5mm)$) ($(emath)-(0,5mm)$)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

% EXAMPLE B
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Heighlighting parts of a code example}
% 1.  Set the code environment as usual and add \tikzref anchors. Here § is used
%     to escape from vermatim back to LaTeX.
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize]
        §\tikzref{z1}§\documentclass[ngerman,11pt]{scrartcl}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{babel}
        §\tikzref{z5}§\usepa§\tikzref{pkgcmd}§ckage{list§\tikzref{pkg}§ings}§\tikzref{lst}§
        §\tikzref{z6}§    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}§\tikzref{lstset}§
        §\tikzref{z7}§    \lstMakeShortInline|§\tikzref{svrb}§
        §\tikzref{z8}§\begin{document}
        Eine \emph{Auszeichnung} und 
        §\tikzref{bvrb}§|verb§\tikzref{verb}§atim|-Text§\tikzref{evrb}§ enthält.
        \dots und eine {unbedeutende Gruppe}.
        % Kommentare erscheinen nicht in der Ausgabe§\tikzref{txt}§
        §\tikzref{z15}§\end{document}
    \end{lstlisting}
% 2.  Add the {tikzpicture} to draw the heiglighting (see example A).
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        % clipping:
        \begin{scope}% [B, see Notes]
            % cut out 1
            \path [clip] let \p1=(z5), \p2=(z7), \p3=(lstset) in%
                ($(z8) + (0,1ex)$) %
                -- ++(\x3-\x1,0) %
                -- ++($(0,0) + (0,2ex) + (0,\y1-\y2)$)
                -- ++(\x1-\x3,0) %
                -- cycle [reverseclip];
            % cut out 2
            \path [clip] %
                ($(bvrb) - (0,1ex)$) %
                -- ($(evrb) - (0,1ex) $) %
                -- ($(evrb) + (0,1ex) $) %
                -- ($(bvrb) + (0,1ex)$) %
                -- cycle [reverseclip];
            % clip everything without cutted areas
            \node [transp,fit=(z1) (z15) (txt)] {};
        \end{scope}
% 3.  Add some additional text annotations using 'nodes' and the \tikzref anchors.
        \def\ddx{0.15}\def\ddy{1ex}\def\dx{0.7}
        \draw<2-> [<-] ($(lst) + (\ddx,0)$) -- +(\dx,0) node [right, anchor=mid west] {load};
        \draw<3-> [<-] ($(lstset) + (\ddx,0)$) -- +(\dx,0) node [right, anchor=mid west] {mono font};
        \draw<4-> [<-] ($(svrb) + (\ddx,0)$) -- +(\dx,0) node [right, anchor=mid west] {short verb};
        \draw<5-> [<-] ($(verb) + (0,-\ddy)$) |- +(0.3,-0.5) node [right, anchor=mid west] {example};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

---

### Notes

- To get a semi transparent overlay with some cut out areas, I lay a node above the whole relevant part of a frame and clip this. The needed `reveseclip`-Option was created by Jake at [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz/12033#12033).
- While designing this example I’ve found out that the direction of drawing clip path **[A]** is relevant so try drawing path (counter) clockwise if it doesn’t work.
- Note that TikZ needs two runs of (pdf)LaTEX to get the right positions.
- In some cases **[B]** it seems to be a good idea to limit the clipping to a `{scope}` to make other drawings which are not effected by it.
- A problem might be that we need to contaminate the original listing code with the `§\tikzref{…}§`. Maybe someone has an idea how to export adjusted listing automatically?

Comment: I just used this idea to make different parts of a slide stand-out at different times.  So I was _right_ to get you to post this code!

Comment: @Tobi can you please post a simpler example? How to animate this in multiple places?

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Can you explain, why you need one? I can’t see many options to simplify my example. At least the second frame “Math” contains an easy example I guess. just ignore the first frame … If you tell me what you don’t understand I’ll add more information and appropriate examples.

Comment: @Tobi Wow, sorry.... i get it now... kool...

Comment: @ATOzTOA: No problem. Your welcome to ask if you got problems with my example ;-)

Comment: It is sad the code is hard to make sense for a new comer. :-/ It is amazing how hard it gets from the \step to this case where we want to highlight different portions over different slides :-(

Comment: @OeufcoquePenteano: I’m not sure what you want to cause with your comment ;-) I added some more information/explanation to my code but I think it's not reasonable to add explanations going back to Adam and Eva. If you don't understand a (more or less) specific part of code first try to find an answer in the manual of used packaged and then ask a specific question in a comment and we'd be happy to help further ;-)

Comment: Sorry Tobi, was just slight frustrated on Latex :-( In any case, I found out that by deleting the text and leaving empty spaces I could fake your approach. Not as neat as leaving the text faded, but works for a newbie like myself. Thanks for adding more comments, and yes I agree you cant go explaining every single detail!