# Animate code blocks beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

I am trying to swap code blocks as animation. But I cannot put `verbatim` inside `\onslide` or `\visible`.

I tried using a `savebox`, the problem is the second code blockis typesetted below the first one. I want the code blocks to show in same location.

My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Object}
    \begin{center} 
    \onslide<2>{
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, fontsize=\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont]
class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
 |
 |  Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
 |  argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
 |  representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
 |  the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
 |  non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
 |  string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
 |  long object will be returned instead.
    \end{Verbatim}
}
\onslide<3>{
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single, fontsize=\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont]
class int(object)
 |  int(x[, base]) -> integer
 |
    \end{Verbatim}
    }
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works with `\only<>` instead of `onslide<>`.

Comment: Would you be amenable to using `Beamer`'s `semiverbatim` environment instead of `fancyvrb`'s `Verbatim`? Beamer and `verbatim` reportedly don't play nice with each other; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396631/latex-semiverbatim-and-fancyvrb and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18073/beamer-and-verbatim-sync.

Comment: You could also use `listings` with blocks: see my answer to [Using \only on a block - beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52663/13304).

Comment: @Jubobs `semiverbatim` cannot be put inside `onslide`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA Yes, it can. Try `\begin{frame}
\onslide<2>{
\begin{semiverbatim}
jsudfhsdfhsdf
\end{semiverbatim}
}
\end{frame}`

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry, my mistake, it compiles. But, semiverbatim won't keep my newlines, also the second slide will come below the first one... back to my original problem...