# Beamer - Using \pause within lstlisting

Tags: beamer, listings, pause

I am preparing a `beamer` presentation and using the `lstlisting` environment in order to put in code. However, I would like to use the `\pause` command within `lstlisting`. By definition that is not possible. I am numbering the lines so it is bad if I just end and begin the environment again in order to insert `\pause`. Any tips?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can escape to LaTeX (Section **4.14 Escaping to LaTeX** of the `listings` documentation) and use `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bera}

\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
numbers=left,
escapeinside=||
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
line1 |\pause|
line2 |\pause|
line3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I have to admit that I didn't look into the documentation. Mia culpa! Newbie mistake. Thank you any way, Gonzalo. You are bailing me out here (also on the other question, thanks!)

Comment: Can we use your answer for `\uncover` as what had been discussed in [How to make overlay still work inside lstlisting environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8384/9467)?

Comment: @Forgiver no; escaping to LaTeX doen't work as expected when `\uncover` or `\onslide` are involved.