# Undesirable beamer behaviour when using \pause inside \align

Tags: beamer

Quite a while (... years) ago I've come across some undesirable behaviour of the `beamer` package when starting to use `\pause` inside `align[*]` environments. I wouldn't have seen it if a

> Package nag Warning: Environment eqnarray is obsolete.

had not motivated me to replace `eqnarray*` with `align*`. Here my MWE:

```latex
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \frame{Undesirable:
      \begin{align*}
        A &= B + C \\\pause
        B &= D + E \\\pause
        C &= F + G
      \end{align*}}
    \frame{Expected:
      \begin{eqnarray*}
        A &= B + C \\\pause
        B &= D + E \\\pause
        C &= F + G
      \end{eqnarray*}}
    \end{document}
```

With `eqnarray*`, `\pause` works perfectly, although [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145911/164050) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144889/164050) post refer to the `beamer` manual suggesting there to be no acceptable solution using `\pause` inside array-like environments. (BTW: Found it helpful to know that `\pause` can be used in [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58922/164050).)

So, thank you for any hints on some non-`amsmath` but `nag`-compliant alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure why you call a documented behaviour "unexpected", but you can find a workaround at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1126

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint. Well, I should have written "undesired" but it has definitely been "unexpected" to me for years until I found some time to search for hints and came across the documentation. So, mea culpa, hope my question is a still valid.