# Problem highlighting listings in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

I'm using `listings` inside `beamer` to typeset some Octave code. Because I want to apply overlay specifications to parts of the listing as I go through the slides (for highlighting purposes), I'm applying the method laid out in [How to make overlay still work inside lstlisting environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-to-make-overlay-still-work-inside-lstlisting-environment)

However, I've noticed that the overlay doesn't apply to one-line comments at the end of a line of normal code. If I place the delimiter on the next line, it works, but it yields an undesired extra space, and using `emptylines=1` does not rid me of the latter.

[image]

Is there a way to also highlight the comments that are on the same line as normal code?

Heree is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}

\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{listings}

% remove navigation symbols 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
}

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
language=Octave,
emptylines=1,
breaklines=true,
basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\color{black!40},
keywordstyle=\color{red!40},
commentstyle=\color{green!40},
moredelim=**[is][\only<+>{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@}{@},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]%{Listings overlay}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=base, gobble=0]
@% This comment will be highlighted; it is also bigger than the frame size so it is expected that line is breaked into at least two. Note that unwanted empty line may be generated
@

@a = 2@ % aaa
@b = 1 % aaa @
@c = 1 % aaa @
@c = 1 % aaa
@

\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, comments in code (a=... % comment) is not highlighted. How can I do it, without generating extra lines (@ in next line)?

Comment: The `@` after a `%` is simply not processed by the `moredelim` option, so the next one is used (which is the reason the first `c = 1` line isn’t even highlighted). You could do `@@b` and `@@c` with omitting the last `@` (to avoid an empty line at the end).

Comment: Yes I know. My approach would be: 1 - detect if after '@' there is a blank line; 2 - If true, remove the line, like 'emptylines=1' does. But I have no clue how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better late than never `:)`

As stated by Qrrbrbirlbel in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel), the problem is that, because `%` is a (one-line) comment delimiter in the `Octave` language, `listings` treats your closing overlay delimiter `@` as part of the comment.

One workaround is to undefine `%` as a comment delimiter, but use `literate` to apply the comment style when that character is encountered anyway. You also need to reset the style at the beginning of each line.

[image]

Two caveats of this approach:

- any `%` character that occurs within a string literal will mess up the highlighting,
- keywords get highlighted even in comments.

---

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}

\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{listings}

% remove navigation symbols 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
}

\makeatletter

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
    language      = Octave,
    emptylines    = 1,
    breaklines    = true,
    basicstyle    = \tiny\ttfamily\color{black!40},
    keywordstyle  = \color{red!40},
    commentstyle  =\color{green!40},
    moredelim     = **[is][\only<+>{\color{black}\lstset{style=highlight}}]{@}{@},
    %
    % Undefine % as a comment delimiter, but still apply comment style when it's encountered.
    deletecomment =[l]\%,
    literate      ={\%}{{\lst@commentstyle\%}}1,
}

% Reset the style at the beginning of every ``true'' line
\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{\lst@basicstyle}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]%{Listings overlay}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=base, gobble=0]
@% This comment will be highlighted; it is also bigger than the frame size so it is expected that line is breaked into at least two. Note that unwanted empty line may be generated
@

@a = 2@ % aaa
@b = 1 % aaa @
@c = 1 % aaa @
@d = 1 % aaa @

\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```