# Do not comment parts of a listing, listings package

Tags: listings

I am using the listings (language=[LaTeX]TeX) package to typeset LaTeX code. When I use \% (text), the package interprets part the string as a LaTeX comment, \ *% (text)*. I need this formatted as \%. Otherwise, the percent character should begin a comment in the typeset listing. My example uses an in line listing but the solution should work for listing environments as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}
\begin{document}
  \lstinline+3\% per annum+ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197722/36296, especially ` deletecomment =[l]\%` and `literate      ={\%}{{\lst@commentstyle\%}}1,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use literate to replace the \% first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,literate={\\\%}{\%}2} % or 1 (less space)
\begin{document}
  \lstinline+3\% per annum+

  \lstinline+3\% % per annum+
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `listings` package knows that for TeX the `%` is the comment start (but still reads the text after it). That's because its contents are read in verbatim. Therefore just use the code as you would use it as a source for your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}
\begin{document}
  \lstinline+3% per annum+ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both 2% and 3\% typeset any following text as a LaTeX comment, and not as code. Try the line "The bank offers a CD at \3% (3%) per annum" and notice change in the font.

Comment: @TomPrice I think I misunderstood your question.