# Escaped percent sign is syntax-highlighted as comment by listings package

Tags: listings, comments, syntax-highlighting

My code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    language=[latex]tex,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{violet},
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    upquote=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo % Comment 1
Bar % Comment 2
Baz \% Not a comment
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Why is `% Not a comment` colored violet when it is not a comment? How can I fix this?

Comment: Inside `lstlisting` environment, backslash character `\ ` is just a normal character, so `\%` is not interpreted as a command anymore. What other contents will you use inside that `lstlisting` environment?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Isn't it a bug in `lstlisting` then? When I have mentioned `[latex]tex` as the language, shouldn't it use LaTeX grammar parsing rules for all content in `lstlisting` environment? I mean, Vim gets it right and does not highlight `\% Not a comment` as a comment. Shouldn't `lstlisting` do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to setup the `\%` as a string:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    language=[latex]tex,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{violet},
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    upquote=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    morestring=[s]\\\%,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo % Comment 1
Bar % Comment 2
Baz \%abc\% Not a comment %still a comment
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the doc of option `morecomment=[s]{<delim>}{<delim>}`, `morestring=[s]\\\%` defines a string delimited by `\\ ` and `\%`. Hence for input `text \large % text`, the characters `\large %` is recognized as a string. I tried options `moretexcs={large}` and `texcsstyle=*<style>`, it seems that the string tokenizer has higher precedence than texcs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use literate to replace the \% with %, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    language=[latex]tex,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{violet},
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    upquote=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    literate={\\\%}{\%}1, % Replace \% with %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo % Comment 1
Bar % Comment 2
Baz \% Not a comment
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer from [Do not comment parts of a listing, listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396996/do-not-comment-parts-of-a-listing-listings-package)

Answer (score 0):

(This only shows some failed attempts, hence is not a standard answer.)

As I commented under [@UlfikeFischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548228), `morestring=[s]\\\%` creates a string pattern which begins at `\\` and ends with `\%`. Therefore for input `text \large % text`, `\large %` is recognized as a string and colored red. And this cannot be overwritten by `morekeywords` and `keywordstyle`.

I also tried `listings` aspect texcs and keyword, none of them succeeds.

- When `comment=[l]\%` is set (this is the default setting), control characters such as `\#` and `\;` can both be set and highlighted as texcs or keywords, but this fails on `\%`.
- When another character other than `%` is used as comment char, then `\%` can be set and highlighted as texcs or keyword.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% a texcs attempt
\lstset{
  language=[latex]tex,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\color{orange}, % the star (*) means highlight the backslash
  commentstyle=\color{violet},
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
  upquote=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  comment=[l], % clear comment setting
  alsoletter={\#\;\%},
  moretexcs={cmd, Foo, AtBeginDocument, \#, \;, \%}
}

\begin{document}
Use \verb|C| as comment character
\begin{lstlisting}[comment={[l]C}]
\cmd \Foo % Comment 1
\#\; Bar % Comment 2
Baz \% Not a Comment
\AtBeginDocument
\end{lstlisting}

Use \verb|\%| as comment character
\begin{lstlisting}[comment={[l]\%}]
\cmd \Foo % Comment 1
\#\; Bar % Comment 2
Baz \% Not a Comment
\AtBeginDocument
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think it is the precedence that matters. It looks like there is a precedence order like "string ~ comment > keyword ~ texcs".