# Using beamer's \uncover with the listings package

Tags: beamer, listings, overlays

I want use `listings` package with uncover command.
He's my code

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{Exemplecode}{}{}

\newenvironment{Framecode}[1]
{\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=Framecode]{#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{frame}{Quelques Rappels}
 \begin{itemize}
   \item<1-> Les Alias.\newline
     \uncover<2->{\begin{Exemplecode}a \end{Exemplecode}}
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I get the following error:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 4.

)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.19 \end{Framecode}

?
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the advice.

This is an exemple of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{Exemplecode}{}{}

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{berkeley}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\newenvironment{Framecode}[1]
{\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=Framecode]{#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Framecode}{Quelques Rappels}
 \begin{itemize}
   \item<1-> Les Alias.\newline
   \begin{Exemplecode} a \end{Exemplecode}
 \end{itemize}
\end{Framecode}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do ?

Comment: You can use the tricks shown in [How to make overlay still work inside lstlisting environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8384/13304) and [Two code blocks working syncronously](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100537/13304). But ultimately it depends on how you want to show the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment (and any descendants created with `\lstnewenvironment`) require the `\end{...}` to be standalone in a dedicated line. This is necessary because of the verbatim processing: Basically `listings` gobbles all lines until it finds a line with the respective `\end{...}` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{Exemplecode}{}{}

\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
\definecolor{epi_brown}{RGB}{139,69,19}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\newenvironment{Framecode}[1]
{\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=Framecode]{#1}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Framecode}{Quelques Rappels}
 \begin{itemize}
   \item<1-> Les Alias.\newline
   \begin{Exemplecode} 
     a 
   \end{Exemplecode}
 \end{itemize}
\end{Framecode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all ! I will ALWAYS write my latex code properly now even when i want just test.