# Overlays in grammar rules

Tags: beamer, overlays, mdwtools

I'd like to use Beamer overlays inside a `grammar` definition:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
  \begin{grammar}
  <term>
    ::=  <term1>
  \only<2>{
    \alt <term2>
  }
  \end{grammar}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but this results in

```
<term> ::= <term1> <2>
    | <term2>
```

(note how `<2>` is, seemingly, picked up by `grammar` instead of `\only`!)

I've also tried `\visible<2>` and `\uncover<2>` (both result in an error `! Argument of \beamer@fakeinvisible has an extra }.`), and `\begin{onlyenv}<2>` (results in `Runaway argument? {onlyenv> \end {grammar} ! File ended while scanning use of \end.`).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18217/36296 might help

Comment: @samcarter: if I understand it right, that answer all hinges on being able to redefine `lstlisting`'s escape character to `§`. But that's "inside out"; here I imagine I'd need to redefine Beamer's `<>` characters so that they don't clash with `grammar`?

Comment: My idea was to just cover up the parts you want to hide with a white tikz shape. I don't know how many of these overlays you intent to have, but if they are not too many, this could just be done by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what I would do is abandon the `grammar` environment. Aside from requiring `fragile` and consuming the `<>` syntax, it also redefines `\alt`. This is essentially death to overlays in Beamer. Everything uses `\alt` so the fact that this is redefined to output a vertical bar and a bit of space is fatal.

The `grammar` environment also looks rather odd in a Beamer slide as it doesn't seem to get placed correctly in terms of spacing. But perhaps that's just me.

Would something like this work?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \synt{term} & ::= & \synt{term1}\\
    \onslide<2->
    & \textbar & \synt{term2}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: syntax with overlay specification]